# Inter service communication

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to store and display a numbers in an ASP.NET MVC4 application fetched from a .NET service and describe the architecture. The website service must communicate with the.NET service using a WCF binding of some sort. The service method shall accept a prime number and return the next greater prime number...what is best design of whole solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are two elements:

- The WCF Service - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/296104/30512) for some great tutorial links
- The ASP.NET logic to consume the service, which [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/01/12/wcf-101-creating-and-consuming-a-basic-wcf-service-hosted-in-iis.aspx) should help with.